# Use Pandas index in Plotly Express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

[Plotly Express](https://plot.ly/python/plotly-express/) allows me to easily plot a pandas dataframe, as explained in their examples. Rather than using a named column for x and a named column for y, I would like to use the dataframe's index for x and a named column for y.

**Example using named columns**

```
import plotly.express as px
iris = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(iris, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

**What i want (bogus example)**

```
import plotly.express as px
iris = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(iris, x="index", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

This obviously throws:

> ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'.
>   Expected one of ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length',
>   'petal_width', 'species', 'species_id'] but received: index

**Ugly fix**

```
import plotly.express as px
iris = px.data.iris().reset_index()
fig = px.scatter(iris, x="index", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Your 'ugly fix' is the recommended approach today :)

Comment: @nicolaskruchten With my own data (pandaframes resuting from some web scraping) I found the "ugly fix" to be the way to go, too. Hence, I'd suggest making your answer (together with a link to some official documentation (I found nothing on that case)) the official answer.

Comment: @StefanQ I'm hoping to actually add support for this kind of thing in the next few weeks :)

Comment: Feel free to post your above remarks as answer and I will mark it accordingly. Makes it easy for you to keep the community up to date!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Reference: https://plot.ly/python/px-arguments/#using-the-index-of-a-dataframe

You can pass the index as reference explicitly.

So in your case, this would be:

```
import plotly.express as px
iris = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(iris, x=iris.index, y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

--

*BONUS QUESTION*: what if `iris` has a `pd.MultiIndex`?

Use [`pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html).

```
import plotly.express as px

# dummy example for multiindex
iris = px.data.iris().set_index(['species', 'species_id', iris.index])

fig = px.scatter(
   iris, 
   x=iris.index.get_level_values(2), 
   y="sepal_length"
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Does this also work with a DatetimeIndex? I am having some difficulties with this issue at the moment

Comment: Note that this geature has been added somewhere after plotly version 4.1 (had to update for this to work).

Comment: This results in the x-axis label being "x". Is there a way to assign so that x-axis uses the label of the index being used?

Comment: The example in the comment would use the name of the index as x-axis label on the plot.

You can try this behaviour with:
```
import plotly.express as px
iris = px.data.iris()
iris.index.rename("my_custom_index", inplace=True)
fig = px.scatter(iris, x=iris.index, y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can simply leave it blank, like so:

```
import plotly.express as px
iris = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(iris, y="sepal_length")
fig.show()
```

Comment: This does not use the index for the x axis! It uses `range(iris.index.size)` as X axis.

Answer (score -2):

You can only pass the column name at x & y parameters of px.scatter(). Seems there is no column named "index" in the iris dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I wanted to point out with my bogus example.