# Plotly: Plotting a time series using plotly and datetime index

Tags: python, datetime, graph, time-series, plotly

I am trying to plot a line graph of the yield spread from 1993 to 2020 using plotly. The name of the variable is "yieldsp" in the dataframe called "data". It is a time-series data with a DateTime index as follows:

```
data['yieldsp'].head()

Date
1993-10-01    2.36
1993-10-04    2.32
1993-10-05    2.29
1993-10-06    2.31
1993-10-07    2.28
Name: yieldsp, dtype: float64

data.index

DatetimeIndex(['1993-10-01', '1993-10-04', '1993-10-05', '1993-10-06',
               '1993-10-07', '1993-10-08', '1993-10-12', '1993-10-13',
               '1993-10-14', '1993-10-15',
               ...
               '2020-06-12', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17',
               '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23',
               '2020-06-24', '2020-06-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=6688, freq=None)
```

I wrote the following code to get the plot:

```
# Using plotly.express
import plotly.express as px

#data = px.data.iris()

fig = px.line(data['yieldsp'], x = data.index, y ='Yield Spread', line_shape="spline", render_mode="svg")
fig.show()
```

But it generated the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-92ef77a6fd5a> in <module>
      5 
      6 fig = px.line(data['yieldsp'], x = data.index, y ='Yield Spread', color="continent", line_shape="spline", 
----> 7               render_mode="svg")
      8 fig.show()

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/tsa_course/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py in line(data_frame, x, y, line_group, color, line_dash, hover_name, hover_data, custom_data, text, facet_row, facet_col, facet_col_wrap, error_x, error_x_minus, error_y, error_y_minus, animation_frame, animation_group, category_orders, labels, orientation, color_discrete_sequence, color_discrete_map, line_dash_sequence, line_dash_map, log_x, log_y, range_x, range_y, line_shape, render_mode, title, template, width, height)
    242     a polyline mark in 2D space.
    243     """
--> 244     return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
    245 
    246 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/tsa_course/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_figure(args, constructor, trace_patch, layout_patch)
   1753     apply_default_cascade(args)
   1754 
-> 1755     args = build_dataframe(args, constructor)
   1756     if constructor in [go.Treemap, go.Sunburst] and args["path"] is not None:
   1757         args = process_dataframe_hierarchy(args)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/tsa_course/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in build_dataframe(args, constructor)
   1311 
   1312     df_output, wide_id_vars = process_args_into_dataframe(
-> 1313         args, wide_mode, var_name, value_name
   1314     )
   1315 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/tsa_course/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in process_args_into_dataframe(args, wide_mode, var_name, value_name)
   1117                         if argument == "index":
   1118                             err_msg += "\n To use the index, pass it in directly as `df.index`."
-> 1119                         raise ValueError(err_msg)
   1120                 elif length and len(df_input[argument]) != length:
   1121                     raise ValueError(

ValueError: Value of 'y' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['yieldsp'] but received: Yield Spread
```

Before posting this question, I also looked at the solution of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178206/use-pandas-index-in-plotly-express) posted in StackOverflow, but that was not using a DateTime index, and so I was unable to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data sample and description of your data is incomplete. You're displaying your data as `data['yieldsp']`, but judging by your attempt to run `px.line` you've got other variables like `continent` in your `data` as well.

Anyway, what you're trying to de here is to run `px.line` on a dataset of  wide format. And that's [possible with the very latest versions](https://medium.com/plotly/beyond-tidy-plotly-express-now-accepts-wide-form-and-mixed-form-data-bdc3e054f891) of `px.express`. But what will *not* work is assigning a string to the `y` method and expect that you'll *name* your line that way. `y` is a method that takes *data* as an argument defined as a string as a reference to your dataset. Using `go.Scatter()` you *could* use `name='yieldsp` to rename your line. But that's not possible here. So the easiest thing here would be to rename your variable in your dataset before plotting. You still haven't provided a complete data sample, but here is how you can build your plot given that `continent` is *not* in your dataset.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# data that hopefullt represents your real world dataset
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '1993-10-01',
                              1: '1993-10-04',
                              2: '1993-10-05',
                              3: '1993-10-06',
                              4: '1993-10-07'},
                     'yieldspd': {0: 2.36, 1: 2.32, 2: 2.29, 3: 2.31, 4: 2.28}})
data.set_index('Date', inplace = True)

# rename 'yieldspd'
data = data.rename(columns={'yieldspd': 'Yield Spread'})

# produce figure
fig = px.line(data, x = data.index, y ='Yield Spread', line_shape="spline")

# show figure
fig.show()
```