# Plotly: How to add date index to dataframe columns so i can make a chart where i can use date as "x" [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have the following dataframe with date stamps and 2 columns:

```
              Gold  Oil
2000-03-31  276.75  29.89
2000-06-30  288.15  31.83
```

I am trying to build the plotly chart where i should put the "date" as an "x" but the output gives me an error of "date" ----> not a column of dataframe as expected [Gold, Oil].

below is the graph i am trying to build:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = gold_data
fig = px.line(df,x='Date', y='Gold', title='GOLD Time Series with Rangeslider')
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)
fig.show()
```

How do i add the Dates as a column to pandas dataframe so i can call it in the graph? I believe its something to do with index bit not 100% sure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your dates are in the index, and the index doesn't have a name. You can reset the index (i.e., have an index that doesn't depend on the dates you have) using the Pandas function `reset_index`. You'll have to name the dates column too.

Comment: This will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57178206/use-pandas-index-in-plotly-express

Comment: new_df=gold_data.copy()
new_df1=new_df.reset_index()
new_df1.columns=["Date","Gold",......]'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your index using `df.index.name = 'Date'`, and then change your call to `px` like this:

```
df.index.name = 'Date'
fig = px.line(df,x=df.index, y='Gold', title='GOLD Time Series with Rangeslider')
```

Even though you can't directly use `x='Date'` above, plotly will know what's up and include the index name in the plot:

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'Gold': {'2000-03-31': 276.75, '2000-06-30': 288.15},
                   'Oil': {'2000-03-31': 29.89, '2000-06-30': 31.83}})

df.index.name = 'Date'

fig = px.line(df,x=df.index, y='Gold', title='GOLD Time Series with Rangeslider')
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True)
fig.show()
```